# YAML doble -- what does mean?

Tags: yaml

Question is ... which is the - - in the last line of the code (before the string "Label1") ? what is it for?

```
version: "2.11"
schema: "spreadsheet-form"
---

sections:
-   elements:
        Label1:
            type: "label"
            value: "TEXto_aqui"
    layout:
    -   - "Label1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `-` is a *sequence item indicator*. Sequences can be nested and this is what happens here.

```yaml
layout:
-   - "Label1"
```

is the same as

```yaml
layout: [ [ "Label1" ] ]
```

It is more clear if you consider this sequence of sequences:

```yaml
- - a
  - b
  - c
- - d
  - e
  - f
```

Which is a sequence of two sequences, the first being `[a, b, c]` and the second being `[d, e, f]`.